# Why it is showing frame pointer in out of 3GB address space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I get the frame at `0xffffd3d0` and saveed `eip = 0xf7e04e7e` in stack level 0 while doing gdb debug.

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffd3d0:
 eip = 0x8048452 in main (test.c:13); saved eip = 0xf7e04e7e
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffd3b8, args:
 Locals at 0xffffd3b8, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffd3d0
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0xffffd3b8, eip at 0xffffd3cc
(gdb)
```

Here is my question about 3GB address space of userspace. Why it is showing frame pointer in out of 3GB address space ?
Normally, the address space of the user space is 0 to `0xc000000` in a 3: 1 virtual address distribution.

Comment: To be clear: yours is a 32-bit process running on a 32-bit kernel, yes?  Because the 3GB limit does not apply to 64-bit processes.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I am running 32 application on 64 bit kernel.  Thanks for your update

Comment: One of you please post that as an answer so that this can be marked as resolved.  Also, please don't abuse the embedded tag, this issue had nothing to do with embedded systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3GB limit does not apply to 64-bit processes